# Map JSON output for iOS

Tags: json, cocoa-touch

I am getting this as result after I do a post. I am not sure what this output is.

a) Is this JSON?

b) When the output is just one customer, the output maps nicely to NSDictionary and  using method valueForKeyPath, I am able to get each element details. However when there are multiple customer or array of customers, I have a problem mapping the output id to a class, I tried mapping to NSArray, NSDictionary without much success. I am using five square software RESTClient (https://github.com/FivesquareSoftware/RESTClient). I want to do http GET or http POST with basic authentication. If I use SOAP UI, the REST service output is proper JSON readable by JSON editor

Trying to figure out what it is.

```
{
    InvoiceQueryResponse =     
    {
        ApplicationArea = {
            CreationDateTime = "2013-02-09T10:30:44-08:00";
            Sender = "Mobile";
        };
        DataArea = {
            InvoiceQueryResponseDetails = {
                Customer = {
                    CommunicationInfo = {
                        EmailInfo = {
                            Email = "lol@test.com";
                        };
                        PhoneInfo = {
                            TelPhoneNO = "000-000-0000";
                            TelPhoneRole = "Home";
                        };
                        PostalAddressInfo = {
                            Address = "7000 200TH ST";
                            City = "LONG ISLAND CITY";
                            PostalCD = "11101-1701";
                            StateProvinceCD = NY;
                        };
                    };
                    InvoiceID  = NY201302_G240
                    CustomerID = G765451;
                    CustomerType = BUSINESS;
                    OrganizationNM = "Therapy Center";
                    PreferredLanguage = "";
                    ProductAssociationsInfo = {
                        TotalProductCount = 2;
                        Product = (
                            {
                                Product1 = "Vitamin B";
                                Qty = 20;
                            },
                            {
                                Product2 = "Vitamin C";
                                Qty = 20;
                            },
                        );
                    };
                };
            };
            ServiceFooter = {
                RecordCount = 1;
                Status = "SUCCESS";
                TimeStamp = "2013-02-09T10:30:46-08:00";
            };
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: no it is not [json](http://json.org/example.htmljson). i guess you should convert it and then map the response with `NSDictionary`

Comment: Also, I don't understand what your 2nd question is. Can't you just use `.0`, `.1`, etc. in the key path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this JSON?

No, it isn't. If it was, the keys would be quoted, and the key-value separators would be colons, like

```
"ApplicationArea": {
    "CreationDateTime": "2013-02-09T10:30:44-08:00";
    "Sender": "Mobile";
};
```

Comment: what about equal signs and semicolons?

Comment: @hgoz Good catch, though one non-compliance is enough to prove that it's not JSON.

Comment: Agreed, It is not JSON. Just was wondering how is this getting converted. The main problem is, I am not able to read the output when there are multiple customers and am trying to figure that out

Comment: @user1509593 I see, but what's the problem with it exactly? What happens when you try to get multiple customers?

Comment: - (void)loadFromJson:(id)json
{
    if ([json isKindOfClass:NSArray.class]) {
  invoiceDetails = [json objectAtIndex:0];
 }
 else if ([json isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.class]) {
  invoiceDetails = json;
 } 
    NSLog(@"Start Invoice Details \n%@\nEnd", invoiceDetails);
}

Comment: @user1509593 What does this code result in? Does anything get logged?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24244/discussion-between-user1509593-and-h2co3)